# PrimeNg p-tabpanel bind headerStyleClass

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am using the tabview component from prime NG and for some reason I cannot bind a header style class.

HTML (this works but is static)

```
<p-tabPanel header="Title" headerStyleClass="badge" formGroupName="groupName">
```

I like to use headerStyleClass with a condition:
(this does not work)

```
<p-tabPanel header="Title" [headerStyleClass]="{'badge': formGroup.get('groupName').dirty}" formGroupName="groupName">
```

How can I bind the class property?

Answer (score 3):

In **headerStyleClass** takes `string` so try passing like this

```
[headerStyleClass]="formGroup.get('groupName').dirty ? 'badge': ''"
```

Comment: I tested it seems to work.Thank you. Weird that my approach didn't work. This approach iIuse if i have an if else condition.

Comment: Welcome. Writting this `{'badge': formGroup.get('groupName').dirty}` actually we are passing object so its not working. But these is acceptable in **ngClass**.